# My spinner items are invisble

Tags: android, spinner

Hi I have a spinner, which contains radio button elements. My spinner loads the elements, but everything is invisible. I think you can understand my situation from the image. an I get any suggestions.[image]

This is the code I am using,

```
   String[] reminder={"5 minutes","10 minutes","15 minutes","20 minutes","25                minutes","30         minutes","35 minutes","45 minutes"};
spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, reminder);
spinnerAdapter
    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice);
 reminder_spinner.setPrompt("Reminders");
reminder_spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
reminder_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new ItemSelect());
```

Answer (score 0):

add this

```
spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);`
```

in your code and  remove

> spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice);`

Comment: ya I tried it, but it removes the radio buttons. I need the radio buttons too.

Comment: No i have tried it now and it is working fine........ here is my code Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
  spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
  ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
  aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
  spin.setAdapter(aa);

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the item text shows up when it is selected leads me to believe it could be a styling issue, ie white font on white background. Here is the layout for simple_spinner_dropdown_item:

```
    <CheckedTextView 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:id="@android:id/text1" 
        style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle" 
        android:singleLine="true" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"/>
```

I would define another xml layout using the above as a template, and pass that to setDropDownViewResource instead.